# Limit Script for Logging Cell Changes to specific rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just starting to fool around with Google Scripts, and a super-novice, so please bear with me here.

I'm currently using this formula to log changes to a particular column in a separate spreadsheet:

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 73 && r.getValue()) {

    var row = r.getRow();

    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quarterly Report");

    if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {
      targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow());
    }

    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

But I'd like to limit 'getRange' to only Column A, Column E, and Column F (i.e., exclude columns B, C, D)

See "[Data Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)" for reference.

Help?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to copy columns A, E, and F to the destination row?  Do you want them in the same columns, or in columns A-C?  (You have multiple getRange calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy those columns A, E, and F to the new location you could do this:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 73 && r.getValue()) {

    var row = r.getRow();

    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quarterly Report");

    if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {
      targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow());
    }

    //Changes Start Here
    var myRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()+1;

    s.getRange(row, 1).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,1));
    s.getRange(row, 5).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,5));
    s.getRange(row, 6).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,6));
  }
}
```

That hard codes the copy location.  Change the 1, 5, and 6 if you want the data in different columns.  You could also use the code [in this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) to better determine the columns and data to store.  The part below

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

reads data from a spreadsheet and can get you to using the first row as a Header in your sheets to retrieve and place the data in columns based on this in your code.  You would want to look at using Objects in javascript to utilize this.  I only mention it to add flexibilty to the code.  It is not necessary if you are ok hard coding the columns.

**EDIT:**
See @utphx response for an interesting way of adding values to specific columns in the row, putting 3 lines of my code into one.  So instead of

```
s.getRange(row, 1).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,1));
s.getRange(row, 5).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,5));
s.getRange(row, 6).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(myRow,6));
```

we could use

```
targetSheet.appendRow([s.getRange(row, 1).getValue(),"","","",s.getRange(row, 5).getValue(),s.getRange(row, 6).getValue()]);
```

Further, captilaize on the speed he gains via his use of the Object returned from reading the entire row, making one call to retrieve the values instead of the 3 I did in my original response:

```
//Retrieve the values if the entire row
var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quarterly Report");
targetSheet.appendRow([source[0][0],"","","",source[0][4],source[0][5]]);
```

I may not use this on sheets with a lot of columns, though, as it defines the contents of each cell between the commas and can get hard to follow.  So if adding an item to column Y you end up with a lot of ,"" inside the brackets. It basically reads:

```
targetSheet.appendRow([column_A_Value,column_B_Value,column_C_Value,column_D_Value,column_E_Value,column_F_Value]);
```

On a spreadsheet with a lot of columns, I would definitly use the information from the above mentioned tutorial to create the getRowsData() function.  Create a Header row in your Target sheet and the following code will allow you to insert or rearrange columns, etc. from either sheet (tab). So below becomes the more flexible solution.  I am not claiming it to be more efficient, nor error checking, just more flexible.  It includes the needed code from teh linked tutorial:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
//  var s =ss.getSheetByName("Current");

  var r = ss.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Current" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue()) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var rowIndex = row - 1;
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var sourceRange = s.getRange(1, 1, row, numColumns);
    // Create one JavaScript object per row of data from the Source data (the Current tab)
    var data = getRowsData(s, sourceRange, 1);

    // Create a JavaScript object for the Target data (the Quarterly Report tab)
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quarterly Report");
    var numRows = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    numColumns = targetSheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetRange = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var targetHeaders = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues().shift();
    var saveData = createArray(numColumns, null);

    //Save the data we will be adding to teh Target in the proper locations in the array
    saveData[targetHeaders.indexOf('Name')] = data[rowIndex].name;
    saveData[targetHeaders.indexOf('Subsidy')] = data[rowIndex].subsidy;
    saveData[targetHeaders.indexOf('Last Update')] = data[rowIndex].lastUpdate;

    //Save the data to teh Target
    targetSheet.appendRow(saveData);  
  }

}

//Create an array with a given number of items and a given common value
function createArray(len, itm) {
    var arr1 = [itm],
        arr2 = [];
    while (len > 0) {
        if (len & 1) arr2 = arr2.concat(arr1);
        arr1 = arr1.concat(arr1);
        len >>>= 1;
    }
    return arr2;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();


   }
  }

  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use append row so you don't have to keep checking if last row is max row:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 73 && r.getValue()) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Quarterly Report");
    targetSheet.appendRow([source[0][0],"","","",source[0][4],source[0][5]])  
  }
}
```